# How to bootstrap angular app in content-script

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to bootstrap Angular app in content-script such that whenever a div is visible the Angular App should be bootstrapped then.

I found a way to manually bootstrap Angular app, code below.

The problem is I would be loading the angular bundle once in the content-script through `manifest` file. However, the specific div can be displayed and destroyed time and again. How to reconcile with this fact?

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 

  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) { 
    // obtain reference to the DOM element that shows status
    // and change the status to `Loaded`
    const dynamicComponentElement = document.querySelector('#sidebar');
    dynamicComponentElement.textContent = 'Loaded';
    // create DOM element for the component being bootstrapped
    // and add it to the DOM
    const componentElement = document.createElement('app-root');
    document.body.appendChild(componentElement);
    // bootstrap the application with the component
    app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
  }

}
```

In the **main.ts** file

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;
  // Otherise, log the boot error
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: have you looked into lazy loading? Would a very small angular app with routing be the way to go? And then just lazy load in your actual app?

Comment: Just to support the question, here is a documentation on how to ["Lazy Loading Images and Videos"](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/), have you looked into it?